# Complex labelling of a BoxWhiskerChart

Tags: labeling, charts

I try and make a complex labelling on a `BoxWhiskerChart`. However, the solution I tried isn't working properly as

```
BoxWhiskerChart[{{{2, 4, 3, 5, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2}, {3, 4, 5, 2, 1}, {1, 5,
     3, 2, 5, 7}}, {{2, 4, 3, 5, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2}, {3, 4, 5, 2, 1}, {1, 
    5, 3, 2, 5, 7}}, {{2, 4, 3, 5, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2}, {3, 4, 5, 2, 
    1}, {1, 5, 3, 2, 5, 7}}}
 , ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"a", "b", "c"}, Axis], 
   Placed[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}, After]}
 , ChartStyle -> {"Pastel", None}
 , BarOrigin -> Left
 ]
```

results in

[image]

Comment: No, the second labels on the plot c1 c2 c3 should be c4 c5 c6.

Comment: `Placed[{{"c1", "c2", "c3"}, {"c4", "c5", "c6"}}, Axis]`

Comment: @corey979 embarrassing – I tried this before and it didn't work ... I must have made a simple syntax error. Apologies. Working now ...

Comment: @corey979 I just tried it with BoxWhiskerChart – which provides a different result.

Comment: Your question is very poorly posed. Is it about bar charts as the title implies, or is it box-whisker charts?

Comment: @m_goldberg My impression was that this functionality would be behave the same for BarCharts and BoxWhiskerCharts. Obviously I was mistaken about this.

Comment: I urge to you to edit your question to eliminate all mention of bar charts; such references are irrelevant, distracting, and degrade your question.

Comment: My dear @m_goldberg, I hope its no longer poor, irrelevant, distracting or degrading. I suggest you phrase your correct suggestions a little more neutral in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the `BoxWhiskerChart` you can use

```
BoxWhiskerChart[{{{2, 4, 3, 5, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2}, {3, 4, 5, 2, 1}, {1, 5, 3, 2, 
    5, 7}}, {{2, 4, 3, 5, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2}, {3, 4, 5, 2, 1}, {1, 5, 3, 2, 5, 
    7}}, {{2, 4, 3, 5, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2}, {3, 4, 5, 2, 1}, {1, 5, 3, 2, 5, 7}}}
 , ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"a", "b", "c"}, Axis], None}
 , LabelingFunction -> (Placed[#2.{3, 1} - 3, After] &)
 , ChartStyle -> {"Pastel", None}, BarOrigin -> Left]
```

[image: Out]

or

```
BoxWhiskerChart[{{{2, 4, 3, 5, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2}, {3, 4, 5, 2, 1}, {1, 5, 3, 2, 
    5, 7}}, {{2, 4, 3, 5, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2}, {3, 4, 5, 2, 1}, {1, 5, 3, 2, 5, 
    7}}, {{2, 4, 3, 5, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2}, {3, 4, 5, 2, 1}, {1, 5, 3, 2, 5, 7}}}
 , ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"a", "b", "c"}, Axis], None}
 , LabelingFunction -> (Placed[Extract[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}, #2], After] &)
 , ChartStyle -> {"Pastel", None}, BarOrigin -> Left]
```

Comment: Looks good – however, do I read this correctly that this only works for the numbers? What if 1,2,3,4,... is an arbitrary string list? E.g. {"a","b","c",...} instead of {1,2,3,4...}

Comment: @MockupDungeon My edit should address your comment.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. That's working. I'll now try and understand the labelling function command.

Comment: @MockupDungeon As a tip for that: Use `{##}` to see what information is available to `LabelingFunction`.

Comment: – Thanks. I'll try this out.